# SQL Server Management Studio times out connecting to a remote SQL Server engine

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, tcpip

I've done this at least a hundred times.

- Install SQL Server on a VPS
- Install it as the default instance
- Only install the engine, not SSMS
- Install Express edition
- Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Enable TCP/IP
- Change port from 1433 to another port
- Open that port in Windows Firewall as Inbound Rule
- Test port using Telnet from another connected machine
- Install SSMS on another machine
- Connect with `IP,Port` format

And one hundred times it worked. Now I'm stuck. I've done all the steps, and client can't connect to the engine. It simply times out. Here's what I've done:

- Increasing time-out in connection window, but getting this error: **A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)**
- Connecting to the engine, from within the VPS, using a `connection.udl` file, and it works just fine
- Making sure that the engine is truly the default instance, using `.` in `connection.udl` and it's confirmed
- Enabling ping following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine). Ping was not enabled by default, but for other VPS instances it was working. I compared their firewalls and their rules were just like each other. Yet this one didn't have ping. I enabled ping and still getting time-out
- Installing SSMS on VPS to test any special thing that I'm not aware of, worked. Though SSMS on remote machine is `12.0.5000.0` and on VPS is `12.0.2000.8`
- Checking the software that I downloaded. I only downloaded the `Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` from [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299), and installed all features of it.

Now I'm totally stuck. I have no idea on what to do next. What other things should I test?

Comment: Maybe this previously-asked question will help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31173/max-connections-sql-server-express-could-have

Comment: That's not the case. It's only me who is trying to connect to this instance. It's only one connection.

Comment: Did you try this: https://sqlserverscribbles.com/2013/02/15/tcp-provider-the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired/